If a person was in a coma for 10 years, failed to file and pay, would IRS demand interest payment?
A quick question on interest abatement. It seems like there's really no reason why IRS could abate interest on underpayment of tax except for a mistake on part of IRS which led to a delay or something.
What if some poor person gets into a car accident and falls into a coma for 10 years while being the only person who knows that he owes gift tax, for instance, but never having the chance to file or pay, and IRS never issues any notice or does not in any way notify anyone from his family or any related tax professional that this person owes this tax. Then if this person wakes up after 10 years of coma, will IRS seriously demand payment of interest for all these years and there's nothing anyone can do?

I’m voting to close this question because this is not a real question. What the IRS will or will not do in a highly hypothetical scenario should be discussed with an attorney, and a PLR requested if necessary.

@littleadv and I thought "real" legal advice would be off topic...

Any legal advice would be off topic, but here we do try to help people understand routine real-life situations with clear-cut outcomes. Important to remember that free answers from anonymous users are worth exactly what was paid for them, in any case.

Tax and interest will still be due. Penalties may be removed or reduced by the IRS if the party acted with reasonable cause and in good faith.
Here's a section of the Internal Revenue Manuals:

Death, serious illness, or unavoidable absence of the taxpayer, or a
death or serious illness in the taxpayer's immediate family, may
establish reasonable cause for filing, paying, or depositing late
[...]


The question is neither about tax nor about penalties. This section of IRM is dealing with penalties, interest is not a penalty.

@littleadv Why isn't interest a penalty?

@DJClayworth penalty is to punish and deter. Interest is to compensate for the lack of access to funds. Generally, interest is assessed and is considered as part of the tax debt, not a penalty. While the penalty abatement rules are relatively "generous" as quoted, and leave a lot of maneuvering space for the RAs, getting the interest abated is much harder, since it's part of the moneys owed, not a penalty to punish. There's a different IRM section dealing with interest under the same chapter, but the part quoted in the answer is irrelevant to the question.

Quoting the IRS page on interest, "We don't remove or reduce interest for reasonable cause or as first-time relief." Having a reasonable cause to pay late might get you out of penalties, but it won't get you out of interest.

Note that this is one of the reasons for having medical proxies and powers of attorney in place, if you have anyone you trust to handle your health and wealth in an emergency where you can't.
